# concourse tagged replease deployment

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

I want to auto deploy tagged releases using concourse. For example, if I tag a release as "stage" it will deploy to staging. There is a tag_filter option for the concourse git resource to do this.

The problem is that it needs to know the branch name in advance so if set up for say master then it will will work fine. However we have hotfixes that may not be merged to master so we don't know the name of the branch in advance, for example hotfix-009. So this solution only works for one branch but tags apply to any branch.

I also saw there is a git multi-branch resource that allows to to specify multi branches to monitor (.*) but this doesn't support the tag_filter parameter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in this way?

The reason I ask is because this doesn't fit very nicely into the Concourse paradigm, and it's usually more helpful to get someone to what they are trying to *accomplish* instead of what they're trying to *do*.

Comment: Hi, I have multiple environments that I want to deploy to. Some of the environments need some manual checks so I need to control the deployment to them. I would be very interested to hear your suggestions/improvements or your experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

The `tag_filter` is glob-compatible, so setting it to something like `stage-*` should do the trick.